# unable to download file from java

Tags: java

I had written a program to get stocks data from yahoo finance website, my code used to work previously, lately it has stopped working.
When i access the same url from browser a file is downloaded,
however from java code i get and empty stream

here is [sample link](http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BAJFINANCE.BO&a=00&b=3&c=2011&d=3&e=24&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv)

These are the codes that i have tried

```
try{


        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels
                .newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(Type+"//"+
                FileName + ".csv");
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0,
                Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();


        String fileName = "file.txt"; //The file that will be saved on your computer                

         URL link = new URL(website.toString());
         //Code to download
         InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int n = 0;
         while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
         {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
         }
         out.close();
         in.close();
         byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         fos.write(response);
         fos.close();
     //End download code

        Runnable r1 = new Analyzer(Type+"//"+
                FileName + ".csv",Type,Name);
    Thread r2=  new Thread(r1);



r2.start();
r2.join();



}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.getMessage();

}
```

Comment: [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File)) might be easier

Comment: We don't know what you `website` is. Anyway, the URL that you gave returns a `301 Moved Permanently` header. Be sure that you set your object to follow redirects.